# ObjectWeb ASM 4.1 Attribute Creation

Tags: java, dsl

org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader has the following "accept" method. I could not figure out how to create the Attributes. Specifically, I would like to get SourceDebugExtension attribute list. Also, notice the document said "prototypes of the attributes that must be parsed". I am wondering what is prototypes of the attributes. Thanks!

```
/**
 * Makes the given visitor visit the Java class of this {@link ClassReader}.
 * This class is the one specified in the constructor (see
 * {@link #ClassReader(byte[]) ClassReader}).
 * 
 * @param classVisitor
 *            the visitor that must visit this class.
 * @param attrs
 *            prototypes of the attributes that must be parsed during the
 *            visit of the class. Any attribute whose type is not equal to
 *            the type of one the prototypes will not be parsed: its byte
 *            array value will be passed unchanged to the ClassWriter.
 *            <i>This may corrupt it if this value contains references to
 *            the constant pool, or has syntactic or semantic links with a
 *            class element that has been transformed by a class adapter
 *            between the reader and the writer</i>.
 * @param flags
 *            option flags that can be used to modify the default behavior
 *            of this class. See {@link #SKIP_DEBUG}, {@link #EXPAND_FRAMES}
 *            , {@link #SKIP_FRAMES}, {@link #SKIP_CODE}.
 */
public void accept(final ClassVisitor classVisitor,
        final Attribute[] attrs, final int flags)
```